# Можно ли задавать "условные (выборочные) ограничения" для обобщенных типов?

Tags: c#, generics, синтаксис, constraints

Мне необходимо узнать, можно ли в С# реализовать ограничения для обобщенных типов по выбору. То есть, чтобы применялось либо первое ограничение, либо второе и тд.

Например, дан класс, реализующий работу с матрицами:

```
public class Matrix<T> {...}
```

И необходимо навесить на тип `T` два (а может и более) возможных ограничения.

Первое:

```
 public class Matrix<T> where T: float {...}
```

Второе:

```
public class Matrix<T> where T: double {...}
```

И превратить это в что-то наподобие:

```
public class Matrix<T> where T: float or double {...}
```

Насколько я понимаю, вариант, приведенный ниже не даст нужного результата, так как в таком случае тип должен будет реализовывать компоненты обоих родителей сразу.

```
 public class Matrix<T> where T: float, double {...}
```

Да, я знаю, что нельзя наследовать от структур. Однако возникла такая необходимость.
Вследствие этого два подвопроса:

1. Можно ли реализовать условное ограничение для обобщенного класса?
2. Можно ли заменить наследуемые `float` и `double` какой-нибудь совокупностью родителя, типа данных или набора интерфейсов, чтобы типу `T` можно было придавать только значения `float` и `double`?

Comment: делаете класс `Matrix<T>`, наследуете от него классы `MatrixInt : Matrix<int>`, `MatrixDouble : Matrix<double>` и тд.

Comment: К сожалению, не получиться сделать generic, придёться делать 2 класса. Хотя можно воспользоваться .NET 6 и новым интерфейсом `INumber`